# Windows 10 Won't recognise My bootable USB

Tags: usb-flash-drive, bootable-media, rufus

I recently created a bootable flash drive with Rufus to install Win 7 on a separate computer. It worked perfectly. However, when I put the same drive back into my laptop with Win 10 the system won't even acknowledge it. It does not show up in device manager. Is it permanently damaged, or can it be recovered? - Thanks.